# K-nearest neighbors to estimate mutual information

Tags: scikit-learn, k-nearest-neighbour, mutual-information

I would like to use the `mutual_info_regression` object from `scikit-learn` to get a rough idea of how well any individual feature in my dataset could explain variation in the target feature.

According to [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.mutual_info_regression.html#id5),

> the function relies on nonparametric methods based on entropy estimation from k-nearest neighbors distances...

and a link to the original [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0305641) is provided.

I am seeking a brief explanation for what this algorithm is actually doing. Practically speaking, this function takes a parameter called n_neighbors, and I'm wondering, what would be the practical difference(s) between choosing a small value versus a large value?